# Installing a dependency already installed by another dependency

Tags: symfony, dependencies, composer-php, yarnpkg

*That's the first time I ask a question on SO, and that's because I couldn't find any keywords matching my problem.*

I have a Symfony application, and I'm using the `easyadmin` bundle downloaded with `composer`. I'll explain the facts with the exemple of `easyadmin`, but my problem could also be on another bundle.

So, the `easyadmin` bundle has several dependencies as `jquery v2.2.0`, `bootstrap v3.3.6`, `Respond.js v1.4.2`, `select2 4.0.1` etc... The dependencies of `easyadmin` were not a problem until now. Indeed, I now need to use the last version of `bootstrap`, which is `4.1.1`.

Like my others front-end dependencies, I'm using `yarn`. All my front-end dependencies are in a folder named `dependencies`, which is located in the 
 `public/asset` folder of my project.

I've already tried to download the last version of `bootstrap` with `yarn`, but I've now two versions of `bootstrap` loaded in my project. **Is that a problem ?**

To illustrate this with javascript files (because my problem concerns both js and css files), I have a `vendor` folder with `easyadmin` inside :

```
- vendor
|
--- easyadmin-bundle
  |
  --- src/Resources/public/javascript/
    |
    --- select2.min.js
    --- bootstrap.min.js
    --- respond.min.js
```

And my folder `dependencies` containing all the dependencies of my project :

```
- public
|
--- asset
  |
  --- dependencies
    |
    --- bootstrap.min.js
```

In my understanding, in this case, I **have to** have the two versions of `bootstrap` in my project. Because `easyadmin` use `bootstrap v3` for its features, and **I** need `bootstrap 4` for my project. **Am I right ?**

And, for exemple, if `easyadmin` use the version 4 of `bootstrap`, do I have to add `bootstrap 4` to my project, or should I use the bootstrap version of `easyadmin` ? I'm confused..

Thanks in advance for your futures answers.

Comment: Remember, EasyAdmin is not part of Symfony. It is a Bundle. Symfony don't incorporate any CSS/JS lib.  
If you need to use EasyAdmin, you will use Bootstrap 3 on your Admin routes. If is not an application that only load all frontend libs once, you can use Bootstrap 4 in your front views. Just configure your view templates for.
If is a One Page App or similar, you must use Bootstrap 3 to avoid troubles with EasyAdmin. 
Take a look at the doc to know more about load libs on front-end.[https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating.html#including-stylesheets-and-javascripts-in-twig].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example having both versions of bootstrap is not a problem, because EasyAdminBundle ships with these dependencies tucked inside the bundle in [src/Resources/public/](https://github.com/EasyCorp/EasyAdminBundle/tree/master/src/Resources/public). Those will be either copied or symlinked into your project's public folder. That means as long as you don't overwrite any of these and don't accidentally mix them up in your frontend logic you should be fine. Not mixing those up should be easy enough as you only require files from your public/asset folder that does not interfere with the ones created by EasyAdminBundle.

You should not rely on the js and css from EasyAdminBundle as you can't control how it is updated. So even if EasyAdminBundle at some point moves to bootstrap 4, I would recommend keeping your frontend dependencies separate from the ones provided by EasyAdminBundle. This advice might not hold up for every bundle that provides assets.

Comment: Thank you @dbrumann, that's the explanation I was looking for. I thought that a duplication of css/js files was a bad practice, but as you said, we sometimes just can't do otherwise.